Determine all Convergent Subsequences (with their limit) of the Sequence $1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, \dots$
Problem: Determine all convergent subsequences (with their limit) of the sequence $1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, \dots$
I know that a subsequence of $\{a\}$ is a sequence $\{b\}$ defined by $b_k=a_{n_k}$, where $n_1<n_2<\dots$ is an increasing sequence of indices.
As an example of a subsequence of {a}, we can consider the constant sequences equal to $1, 2,$ or $3$; all these sequences are convergent. However, I don't know how to determine all possible subsequences. I can't figure out how to proceed to identify them.
Could someone help me understand how to find all the subsequences of a given sequence?

Please edit to include your efforts.  As, perhaps, a simpler question:  what can you say about any convergent sequence of integers?

For a subsequence of this sequence to converge, it will have to eventually be constant. That is a fine verbal description of the subsequences you are looking for. And if you work at it, you can use this to define the subsequences for explicitly (if that is required).

I think a better approach would be to think about what "convergent" means rather than "subsequence". You're not trying to determine all possible subsequences, you're only trying to find those with a very specific property. And if you think about that property (maybe right down a definition?), you'll find it is very limiting.

Possibly help to think about boundedness ob subsequence.

"...you'll find it is very limiting." Pun intended, @Adam?

While only for $1$, $2$ and $3$? For every non-zero natural number, you can find a convergent subsequence.

An integer sequence converges if and only if it ends up being constant, because it cannot come arbitrarily closer to its limit over an infinite number of steps. In consequence, convergent subsequences have constant tails, whatever comes before. Actually, that is easier to say it worldly than mathematically; the set of such subsequences can be translated as $S = \{b_k \;|\; \exists K \in \Bbb{N} \text{ s.t. } b_k = a_{n_k} = const \;\forall k \ge K\}$.
As a side note, it has to be highlighted that, in your particular case, the said constant tails are made of elements $a_{T_n+m} = m+1$, where $0 \le m \le n$ and $T_n = \frac{1}{2}n(n+1)$ is a triangular number (starting from $n = 1$).
